# How to use filter in data table - Shiny - R

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I've this Shiny code example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
x = read.xlsx("my_path\\2.xlsx") #my file I want to use
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             DTOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$table <- renderDT(iris,
                             filter = "top",
                             options = list(
                               pageLength = 5
                             )
    )
  }
)
```

When I click on some filter I get a list of all the possible values:

[image]

But when I use my file (x), instead of iris - it doesn't work and the list doesn't open
any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Not knowing your file, I'll have to guess. Have you tried to wrap the column in question within `as.factor`?

Comment: Is your data/file shown properly in the table or is just the filter not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this with the column you want to make searchable:

```
x$column <- as.factor(x$column)
```

The Species column in the Iris dataset is a factor; when using character columns, DT will allow you to type in possible values.